# Calling component's method from shared service

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to call the [sidenav](https://material.angular.io/components/component/sidenav) component's method `open()` from my shared service. If I call the method directly from component, it's working fine. But as soon as I call the same method from a shared service I got a error message:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined

**Sidenav component:**

```
import { MdSidenav } from '@angular/material';
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sidebar-content',
  template: `
   <md-sidenav-container class="container">
     <md-sidenav #sidenav class="sidenav">
       Jolly good!
     </md-sidenav>

     <app-main-content></app-main-content>

   </md-sidenav-container>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./sidebar-content.component.css']
})
export class SidebarContentComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('sidenav') el: MdSidenav;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  openSideNav() {
    this.el.open();    
  }

}
```

**Shared service:**

```
import { SidebarContentComponent } from './../content/sidebar-content/sidebar-content.component';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';


@Injectable()
export class SharedService {

  constructor(private sc: SidebarContentComponent) { }

  openSidenav() {
    this.sc.openSideNav();
  }

}
```

**Calling the open method from another component:**

```
import { SharedService } from './../../services/shared.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { SidebarContentComponent } from './../sidebar-content/sidebar-content.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-main-content',
  templateUrl: `
   <div class="sidenav-content">
       <app-toolbar></app-toolbar>
       <button md-button (click)="open()">
         Open sidenav
       </button>
       <button md-button (click)="openWithService()">
         Open sidenav with service
       </button>
   </div>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./main-content.component.css']
})
export class MainContentComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private sc: SidebarContentComponent, private ss: SharedService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  open() {
    this.sc.openSideNav();
   // Works fine
  }

  openWithService() {
    this.ss.openSidenav();
  // Throws an error
  // ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined
  }

}
```

Comment: You don't set the SidebarContentComponent of the service, that's why it set that it's undefined. Putting it in the constructor does not work: it could be any SidebarContentComponent even though you probably have only one.

Comment: The design is wrong. Services are injected into components, not vice versa. You can't 'inject' a component into a service. Technically, you can because components are injectable classes, but it won't work properly, as we see here.

Comment: @estus I think that the right way to do it in this situation is to use an rxjs/subject and let the service propagate the method call to its subscribers.

Comment: I just want to control the opening of the sidenav from everywhere in my app. So for e.g. if I have buttons in different components, I don't want to every time inject the sidenav component.

Comment: @Gabriel then use an rxjs subject in your service and let your component (the one with the sidenav) subscribe to it.

Comment: Thank you @Ploppy I will try ;)

Comment: @Gabriel I posted an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not set the SidebarContentComponent of your service. Even though you could do it, I think that the proper way is to use an rxjs/Subject.

This should do it:

SharedService

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject'; // don't forget to import it!

public open$: Subject<any> = new Subject();
```

SidenavComponent

```
this.sharedService.open$.subscribe(() => this.openSideNav());
```

AnyComponent

```
this.sharedService.open$.next();
```

Comment: I don't know why I'm getting the `Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for SidebarContentComponent: (?).` error

Comment: I don't think that it's related to my code. Where is this error located at ?

Comment: It's in SidenavComponent. Just for clarification, I need to inject the service into the Sidenav component and after that subscribing to the subject in the ngOnInit hook?

Comment: Yes. And don't forget to remove the `constructor(private sc: SidebarContentComponent)` from your service.

Comment: This was the issue. Thank you @Ploppy. Btw what is you recommendation if I want to learn more about rxjs (books, courses)

Comment: I don't read books nor do courses. I learn from the docs online. You can get the basics of rxjs [here](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html), once you know it, you'll get the most out of rxjs by learning the operators [learnrxjs.io](https://www.learnrxjs.io/).

Comment: Also the most common operators are marked [here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/complete.html)